# Is there a word for when something's name completely fits the description or personality?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, names, story

for example in a story i'm writing, there is a character named Revenge who's main goal is to get revenge. Is there a single word for that?

Comment: Someone had the term for it here yesterday, but they were misusing term and I've forgotten what it is.

Comment: Ah, here it is: [autological](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/autological).

Comment: But I've forgotten it again!  (You have my permission to craft your own answer.)

Comment: @HotLicks An autological word describes the _word_ itself, not the referent for the word. The word 'short' is autological because the word 'short' is short. The name of a person which describes the person accurately is not describing the name but the person. It is appropriate or apropos (though I am sure there is a more specific word for the situation).

Comment: You might like to look up "nominative determinism"

Answer (score 0):

A modern term is **aptonym**. It is a play on “apt” (appropriate) and the “-onym” root for name. It is usually for jobs or qualities, not just personalities. Like a person named John Cooke who is a chef, or Usain Bolt is the fastest sprinter.

Comment: Should link to the dictionary url for OP's perusal.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "[aptronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym)"?

Comment: As seen in the link, either one. It’s a portmanteau.

Comment: Where does the *r* come from?

Comment: *Aptonym* is generally used in cases where the person's name is a normal name that coincidentally matches their situation. I've never heard it used in the character-named-Revenge sense mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> **Charactonym:** A name given to a literary character that is descriptive of a quality or trait of the character.

— [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/charactonym)